# Syntax for creating View delegate in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, macos, syntax

I am trying to create a delegate protocol for a custom UIView. Here is my first attempt:

```
@protocol FunViewDelegate
@optional
- (void) funViewDidInitialize:(FunView *)funView;
@end


@interface FunView : UIView {    
@private
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) id<FunViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

This doesn't work because the FunView interface has not been declared at the time of the FunViewDelegate declaration. I have tried adding a prototype ala C++ before the @protocol:

```
@interface FunView;
```

But this just drives the compiler nuts. How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forward class syntax is `@class Foo;`, not `@interface Foo;`.

Answer (score 9):

It would seem that you can forward declare protocols:

```
@protocol FunViewDelegate;

@interface FunView : UIView {    
@private
    id<FunViewDelegate> delegate;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<FunViewDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol FunViewDelegate
@optional
- (void) funViewDidInitialize:(FunView *)funView;
@end
```